# Installing a second version of e.g. git, perl and or python on osx lion

Tags: python, perl, git, osx-lion

At the moment i am running git 1.7.5.4, perl 5.12.3 as well as python 2.7.1 on osx 10.7.3, which were all included in the basic system setup. Applying the "which" command the locations are:

```
/usr/bin/git  
/usr/bin/perl  
/usr/bin/python
```

I wanted to keep those versions untouched and upgrade and install the latest ones aside. If they are installed within '/usr/local/bin' and inside of '.bash_profile' '/usr/local/bin' is placed at the first position of 'export PATH=' and you are applying 'which' afterwards the location would be:

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

Now the question is which version of git, perl and or python osx would be using. Basically i guess it would use the versions from '/usr/local/bin' too? Or are the absolute paths of '/usr/bin' been hardcoded within the parts of osx and xcode requiring them? Thanks r.

Comment: For Perl, you might want to look into [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew).

Comment: For git, grab the source code of it and compile it with your desired `--prefix`. Also, `MacPorts` installs softwares under /opt/, it will not touch those that come with your system installation. I don't like MacPorts cause it's quite slow compared to `HomeBrew`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install your own versions of the programs in `/usr/local/bin` or any other directory of your choosing that you place on your PATH ahead of `/usr/bin` etc.  I do this all the time for both Perl and Git; I don't use Python so much.

The scripts that are distributed by Apple will likely continue to use the system-provided tools.  Indeed, the reason I install my own Perl is so that regardless of what I do in the way of installing extra modules, I won't be breaking anything the system uses (probably).  I've never run into problems, at any rate.  My programs use my versions; other people's programs configure themselves to use whatever they see fit; the system continues to work.

Comment: Yup. This is also [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)' default installation path.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

You can install git and python and probably also perl with it. For perl I use perlbrew with which you can have multiple versions of perl concurrent, but for one (the latest) version, homebrew should also work here.